# displaying text/links in Plotly dashboard

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard, plotly-python

I've been trying for the longest to figure this out. I would just like to take the output from this function and make it into a dash app page.
I've tried dcc.Markdown but it displays the text exactly as written.
I don't have an input so I'm not sure how to callback what I want without one.

Would would be the easiest way to go about it?

```html
url1 = "https://google-news1.p.rapidapi.com/search"
querystring1 = {"q":"bitcoin","lang":"en","limit":"10","when":"1h","exact_phrase":"bitcoin"}
headers1 = {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "google-news1.p.rapidapi.com"
}
response1 = requests.request("GET", url1, headers=headers1, params=querystring1).json()

def get_news():
    for x in response1['articles']:
        title = (x['title'])
        link = (x['link'])
        print(f"{title}\n{link}")
        
get_news()
```

the code will return something like this:

What Does Michael Saylor Think of Bitcoin Right Now? - The Motley Fool
https://www.fool.com/investing/2022/07/06/what-michael-saylor-thinks-of-bitcoin-right-now/

Binance Removes Bitcoin Trading Fees In Fifth Anniversary - Bitcoin Magazine
https://bitcoinmagazine.com/business/binance-removes-bitcoin-trading-fees

etc...

I just want this, but on a dash app via Plotly. No search or anything needed, it would just refresh whenever the page loads.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Set up your initial `layout`, and then use a callback to populate the text and links by listening to a `dcc.Location` component and outputting to some container in the layout. That will make it run when the page loads. Just put each item into a `dcc.Link`.